# Correct way to import 3rd party js library cq-prolyfill in an angular 5 app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to get the cq-prolyfill library to function when included through a typescript import statement E.G. `import 'cq-prolyfill/cq-prolyfill.min.js';` in an angular module. I can see that it's being included in my vendor bundle, however the initial self invoking function within the library doesn't seem to be called. If I include the library via an html head import E.G. `<script src="assets/js/cq-prolyfill.min.js"></script>` it works as expected. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import the script as a module you get a factory function that has to be called to enable the polyfill.

The following code snippet should work:

```
import * as cqProlyfill from 'cq-prolyfill/cq-prolyfill.min.js';
cqProlyfill({
    // Configuration...
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! (Had to run `cqProlyfill.default();` to get it to work in our setup)